# Динамическое создание столбцов DataGrid-а журнального вида

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Допустим, у нас есть обычный DataGrid, который заполняеться из оперделенной коллекции (например, это группа студентов: Фамилия | Имя | Отчество | Телефон). 
Здесь всё понятно.

Собственно вопросы:

1. Как динамически создавать столбцы взависимости, например, от дней недели (т.е. Заголовки: Понеделник | Вторник | Среда ...)
2. Как сформировать "журнальную структуру" в DataGrid (например: заголовки столбцов - дни недели, первый столбец - список студентов, остальный столбцы: например,на пересечении столбца с заголовком "День недели" и строки с ФИО студента должна стоять метка (не был, был, болел)

На картинках видно, что я имею в виду. 
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В WPF DataGrid не использовал, только Grid, но по идее у столбцов и строк должны быть свойства Colspan и Rowspan, соответственно, которые отвечают за кол-во совмещённых столбцов/строк. Работает аналогично таблицам в html

Comment: Какой функционал требуется потом от этой таблицы? Чисто отображение в удобном виде? Или что-то еще?

Comment: Отображение и редактирование

Comment: Возможно проще будет отказаться от DataGrid вообще и собрать всё из маленьких кирпичиков. DataGrid не самым лучшим образом поддается кастомизации